# Disabling log messages for all libraries

Tags: python, logging

I want logging messages from my program, but not from the libraries it uses.  I can disable / change the logging level of individual libraries like this:

`logging.getLogger('alibrary').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

The problem is, my program uses lots and lots of libraries, which use lots themselves.  So doing this individually for every library is a big chore.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the root logger's level to e.g. `ERROR` and then selectively set more verbose levels for your own code:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

then assuming the libraries you use are well-behaved with regard to logging, the effective levels of their loggers should effectively be `ERROR` just as if you had set each one individually.

Comment: I do that also, actually.  I have one file (module) that calls another file (module) that in turn calls all of the libraries with their chatter.  Should the line you've given be included in each of my source files, then?